# Correctness of exercise and solution, related to a exponential distribution

Tags: poisson-process, exponential-distribution

I find this exercise somewhere

> The distance between two big fissures on a highway have an exponential distribution with mean $5$ miles. What is the probability that in a section of the road of $10$ miles will be two fissures?
>
> Answer: $0.8647$.

If $X\sim\rm Exp(5)$ then the value of the proposed answer coincides with $\Pr[X\le 10]$. However it is not clear to me how this answer is achieved (I suppose that some assumptions are needed to achieve this answer).

To me $\Pr[X\le 10]$ means "the probability that the distance between two fissures will be at most $10$ miles", but how this statement can imply that in a stretch of $10$ miles the probability of (at least) two fissures will be the same? What kind of extra assumptions we need to show this implication?

An assumption could be supposing an underlying [homogeneous Poisson process](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Poisson_point_process#/Homogeneous_Poisson_point_process) of parameter $\lambda$, then we reach the desired implication, but to me it is not clear that we can make this assumption easily from the text of the exercise.

My questions are two:

1. The answer of the exercise, without any extra assumption, make sense?
2. If not, what are the minimal number of extra assumptions we need to arrive at the proposed solution?

Comment: In my opinion, even if we were to go with the Poisson model, the question is asking about the count being exactly 2. That is, if $Y$ models the *number* of fissures in a section of the road of 10 miles, then $Y$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda \times t = (1/5)*10 = 2$. Then as worded the question asks for $P(Y=2)$ which is $\frac{e^{-2} 2^2}{2!}$ which is not 0.8647. So something is amiss!

Comment: @Just_to_Answer yes, I know... it seems that the exercise is very bad wordy.

Comment: Well, the answer seems to match the probability of encountering a second fissure within $10$ miles, conditional on having encountered a first one... (Unless I’m confused, in which case I really need to sleep.)